# Does Internet Explorer 11 support border-image?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, css

As the title, does Internet Explorer 11 support border-image?

Because if i use this CSS:

```
.windowtemplate {
    border: 18px solid black;
    -webkit-border-image: url("../images/windowtemplate/boxtemp.png") 18 18 18 18 round round;
    -moz-border-image: url("../images/windowtemplate/boxtemp.png") 18 18 18 18 round round;
    border-image: url("../images/windowtemplate/boxtemp.png") 18 18 18 18 18 round round;
}
```

works in all other browsers (Chrome, Safari, Firefox) except IE11.

There is an other way to make border-image work in IE11?

Comment: Does Internet Explorer 11 support border-image?: Answer: [Yes](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-image).

Comment: Have you checked that the browser is in IE11 standards mode? This feature won't work in quirks mode or compatibility mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the note on http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-image:

> Note that both the border-style and border-width must be specified for
>   border-images to work according to spec, though older implementations
>   may not have this requirement. Partial support refers to supporting
>   the shorthand syntax, but not the individual properties
>   (border-image-source, border-image-slice, etc).

It seems IE 11 is one of those browsers that does need these two properties for the `border-image` to appear.

Comment: Considering that the two required properties *are* set in the question, I'm not so sure this applies. The real problem, though, is that it *should* work in IE11. The problem in the question simply cannot be reproduced in its current form.

Answer (score 1):

I would better use the split syntax.

This web can be very helpful:

[border image generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Tools/Border-image_generator)

Comment: the split syntax fixed this for me in IE11!