# IE 11 does not recognize border-image on my website

Tags: wordpress, css, internet-explorer-11, border-image

On my Wordpress http://www.diylowell.org/test/Wordpress/

I have a border-image set for posts in my widget area with the following CSS:

```
  #secondary .widget_siteorigin-panels-postloop .post {
        border: 30px solid transparent;
        -webkit-border-image:url("border-thick.png") 30 stretch;
        -moz-border-image:url("border-thick.png") 30 stretch;
        -o-border-image:url("border-thick.png") 30 stretch;
        border-image:url("border-thick.png") 30 stretch;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
    }
```

The border-image shows in multiple versions of Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, but for some reason does not work in IE11. I've checked with the F12 function, and IE acts as if it doesn't recognize the attribute (puts a wriggly line under it.)

I've even copied and pasted CSS from other websites whose border-images are working in IE11 into my own site, and it doesn't work. Could there be some sort of code in my theme or plugins that prevents border-image from working in IE11?

Answer (score 0):

This *might* answer your question:

[Does Internet Explorer 11 support border-image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378917/does-internet-explorer-11-support-border-image)

> Note that both the border-style and border-width must be specified for
>   border-images to work according to spec, though older implementations
>   may not have this requirement. Partial support refers to supporting
>   the shorthand syntax, but not the individual properties
>   (border-image-source, border-image-slice, etc).

Yes, you may have done: `border: 30px solid transparent;` however IE11 seems to require you to define border-style and border-width separately, not from the `border:` property.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! However, I'm not sure it's a problem with the syntax of the code. It works in jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/kxpcLjLu/1/

But not when it's in the webpage with exact same CSS, even breaking it up into border-style, border-width, etc.

Answer (score -1):

In a similar case, I specified `border: solid` and `border-width: 0 0 5px 0`, and the bottom border was displayed as desired, both in IE (11) and Chrome.

I commented out `border: solid` and the border image disappeared in IE, but remained in Chrome.

Specifying `border: solid` should work.

Comment: "Specifying `border: solid` should work." I'm not an expert on CSS, but I think your answer won't help the OP, because he already has `border: 30px solid transparent;`. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Leb: Other than the first sentence, this definitely seems to be an attempt at answering the question, and from what I know of CSS, is fairly plausible. (I haven't tried it, so I don't know if it actually works, though.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But as others mentioned, I've tried both the shorthand and longhand syntax to no avail. The confusing thing to me is that both syntaxes work in js-fiddle, but not on my website. (I've learned to live with bad performance in IE-11, but still hope to learn what went wrong.)