# Why is my border-image not working in IE11?

Tags: html, css, border

I have the following code for a custom border of a div element perfectly working in FF, but for some reason the border-image is not displayed in IE11:

CSS:

```
#example-border {
  border-color: orange;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  border-image: url("Box.jpg") 5 5 5 5 stretch stretch;
  -webkit-border-image: url("Box.jpg") 5 5 5 5 stretch stretch;
  -moz-border-image: url("Box.jpg") 5 5 5 5 stretch stretch;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="example-border" >
    <h2>Headline</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vel tellus enim. Fusce quam leo, pulvinar in sodales a, placerat et arcu. Nunc ut sapien orci. Vestibulum facilisis faucibus nisl at ultricies. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed a purus quis lorem adipiscing tempus. Nullam et faucibus elit. Proin eget mauris orci, et egestas dolor. Nulla vulputate, mi nec bibendum vestibulum, augue nisl imperdiet risus, sed rhoncus velit neque in nisi.</p>
</div>
```

Any Idea how to get this working in IE11?

Thanks, Christoph

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Internet Explorer 11 support border-image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378917/does-internet-explorer-11-support-border-image)

Comment: Works for me, when I use a known working image file: http://jsbin.com/qopiliqunu/1/edit so what is it that goes wrong?

Comment: Your example works in my IE11. But as soon as I use your code in a lokal HTML file the border-image is not diplayed (with lokal or online image).

Comment: Ok. It's working, as long as the HTML file is on my Desktop. When the file is in some folder on my file system, it wont work. I'm very confused. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Christoph Are you sure the HTML file can find the image file when they're in different folders?

Comment: They are both in the same folder. Desktop or in the filesystem. Maybe it's because it's a mounted network drive? I thought that shouldn't matter, but obviously for IE it does :-)

Answer (score -1):

In IE 11 , border-image attribute is unknown, you can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/border-image)

Comment: You misinterpret the browser compatibility table on that page; it says that IE11 has "basic support" since v11.