# Border image with svg views differently in Internet Explorer than in Chrome, how to fix that?

Tags: css, border-image

Border image is a svg file.

This is how it looks in Chrome:

[image]

This is how it looks in IE 11.

[image]

I followed the suggestion here: [Does Internet Explorer 11 support border-image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378917/does-internet-explorer-11-support-border-image)

And this the CSS code:

```
.file-list {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
    border-image-repeat:stretch stretch;
    border-image-source: url("Images/greenframe.svg");
   border-image-slice: 100;
    border-image-repeat: repeat;
    display: block;
    margin: 0.5em;
    padding: 0.5em;
}
```

I tried the generator in this link too and tried that code:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Border-image_generator

```
border-image-source: url("Images/greenframe.svg");
border-image-slice:27 27 27 27;
border-image-width:20px 20px 20px 20px;
border-image-outset:0px 0px 0px 0px;
border-image-repeat:stretch stretch;
```

How can I make the border image look like in Chrome ?

Comment: Did you try this? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Border-image_generator

Comment: @Martin I did try it but still it doesn't work in IE. I don't know why.